# "1 euro a oggetto" oppure "1 euro per oggetto"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, prepositions

Sto cercando di capire quale di queste forme sia corretta o comunque preferibile dovendo indicare il costo di un oggetto.

Esempio:

> 1€ a penna
>
> 4€ a confezione

oppure

> 1€ per penna
>
> 4€ per confezione

Facendo delle ricerche in internet mi sembrano usate entrambe le forme e se dovessi scegliere andrei a sensazione e vorrei capire se c'è una regola.

Comment: Confermo che entrambe le forme sono usate, anche se la prima mi suona più naturale in questo caso. Purtroppo non sono a conoscenza di nessuna "regola" per quando usare una piuttosto che l'altra.

Comment: La più comune di tutte mi sembra "1 Euro l'una".

Comment: A intuito, credo che la prima forma sia più informale della seconda, ma credo si possano usare entrambe.
Un'altra alternativa è "1€ cad." ma mi sembra un po' più desueta.

Comment: Io userei la forma con *a* per parole che iniziano per consonante e la forma con *per* per le altre

Answer (score 2):

`1€ a penna`

In molti casi *A* suona decisamente meglio rispetto che *per*.

Alcuni esempi:

```
Tutto a 1 euro 
10€ a partita
1€ a testa
```

Possiamo invece utilizzare *per* in frasi come

```
1€ per 50 prodotti 
10€ per tutto insieme 
10€ per l'intera collezione
```

Una regola potrebbe essere che quando il prodotto che viene venduto è formato da 
**più** di una parola si utilizza *per* mentre invece, se il prodotto è una sola parola suona meglio *A*